# Shell script to copy,rename and change owner permissions of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

First time posting a question here so sorry in advance.
I want to write a script that copies a list of files from one directory to the other. During copying the script should capitalize the first letters of the file name and lowercase all the other letters. Also, change the owner of the file to a given owner and change the permission to give a set of permission.

I am new to shell scripting so I only have knowledge about commands like CP, MV, RENAME and I don't want to use any more advanced commands even if it could make my life easier.

This code here only displays all the files in the directory I can't figure out a way to solve my problem

```
cd [directory]
for i in *
do
    echo "$i"
done > filename.txt
```

What I want is it to ask me about Source directory, Destination directory and Owner/permissions and script will do the rest.

Comment: `and I don't want to use any more advanced commands even if it could make my life easier.`
Really? So you basically tells you want we do stuff for you without the tools to do it. Too bad, because `install` `read` and Bash string manipulation or `sed` would have been able to do what you want. But since you expressly don't want to use anything more complex than `mv` `cp` `cd`. We have no help for you either.

Comment: This looks like a homework IMO. you should learn about "how to pass variables in shell script" for your problem

Comment: CP, MV, RENAME = these commands cannot achieve what you are looking for unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting challenge, I'll bite, but I'll have to use more tools than you said, since it cannot be done otherwise.

**Problem 1 - changing the case of the file names:**

Bash has variable expansions that let you change the casing in a variable.

```sh
f="my FILENAME in Mixed cap"
g=${f,,}  # $g is now $f all in lower case; ${f,} would only lower the first letter
h=${g^}   # $h is now $g with the first letter capitalized; ${g^^} would upper c the whole string
```

**Problem 2 - changing ownership**

This can only be done using `chown`, there is no way around it.

```
chown new_owner file
```

In most cases, you won't have permission to do this, so you would need `sudo` to do it, or run the whole script as `root`. However, if you want the new owner to be yourself, that will happen by default when you run `cp`, so you won't need to do anything special to make it happen.

**Problem 3 - changing permissions**

Here, you need `chmod`, and again, there is no way around it.

```
chmod new_permission file
```

**Problem 4 - cd source invalidates dest path**

If the destination directory is not an absolute path, `cd $source` will invalidate it. We can use `pwd` to fix that.

```
dest=some/dir
if [[ $dest !~ ^/ ]]; then
   dest=`pwd`/$dest
fi
```

This bit of script uses bash's built-in regular expression matching checks if the first character of the destination directory is a slash, in which case it is an absolute path (I'm assuming a *nix OS here). Otherwise, we make it absolute by prepending it with the current directory. I'm also assuming you're using bash 4.

**Putting it together**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
source=$1
dest=$2
owner=$3
perm=$4

if [[ ! $dest =~ ^/ ]]; then
   dest=`pwd`/$dest
fi

cd $source
for f in *; do
   g=${f,,}
   h=${g^}
   cp "$f" "$dest/$h"
   chown "$owner" "$dest/$h"
   chmod "$perm" "$dest/$h"
done
```

**Calling this script**

You could use `read` to read in the parameters from the terminal, but I much prefer using command-line arguments.

Call the script what you want, say `script.sh`, make it executable, and invoke it this way:

```
script.sh source_path dest_path new_owner new_perms
```

**Caveats**

- You didn't say you wanted recursive copying, so I didn't handle directories in `$source`. That could be handled too, but would be quite a bit more complex.
- I've done no error checking. I've tested my script and it works, but make sure `$dest` exists before you start, and that it doesn't contain anything you don't mind overwritten!

Comment: OMg, it works like a charm I could never think of the problem this way and your explanation was way better than my teacher LOL. Just a minor doubt for permission passing as a command line which should i prefer I mean chmod works with r w x or numbers like 0,1,2,4

Comment: Glad to help. For the permissions, you can use any format accepted by `chmod`: `+rx`, or `777`, or whatever else works directly in `chmod`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
SrcDir=/kjdfskdf/ksdfjsdjkf
DestDir=/dest

for Name in *
do 
OrgName="$Name" # save org file name
Name=$(echo $Name| tr [:upper:] [:lower:])  # change all to lower
Name=$(echo ${Name:0:1} | tr  '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')${Name:1} # change first char 
echo cp -R $SrcDir/$OrgName $DestDir/$Name  # display cp cmd recursive - if all 
# correct 
# delete echo
done
```

Comment: Thanks, mate that really helped me out.

Comment: PS: when I check my destination folder I can only see . and .. and no other file is copied I can figure out why.                                           `SrcDir=/home/rushi/Folder1
DestDir=/home/rushi/Folder2

for Name in SrcDir
do 
OrgName="$Name" # save org file name
Name=$(echo $Name| tr [:upper:] [:lower:])  # change all to lower
Name=$(echo ${Name:0:1} | tr  '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')${Name:1} # change first char 
echo cp -R $SrcDir/$OrgName $DestDir/$Name  # display cp cmd recursive - if all 
# correct 
# delete echo
done`

Comment: you must delete the echo : cp -R $SrcDir/$OrgName $DestDir/$Name

Comment: LOL Thanks that was so stupid of me.

Comment: no problem. if you will change owner or permissions you can add in the loop:     chmod  666 $DestDir/$Name # this only example  and  chown newuser:newgroup  $DestDir/$Name

Answer (score 0):

This script can be used to achieve the result.

```
#!/bin/bash
source="."
destination="testdir"
permission="+x"
ownername="someone"
while IFS= read -r line; do
  foo=$line
  foo="$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< ${foo})"
  foo="$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< ${foo:0:1})${foo:1}"
  cp $source/$line $destination/$foo
  chmod $permission $destination/$foo
  chown $ownername $destination/$foo
done < file.txt
```

In this script, the `file.txt` contains the names of files to be copied and variables - `source` for source directory, `destination` for destination directory, `permission` for the permissions to set and `ownername` to set the owner name.

To take the parameters from the command line instead of hardcorded values you have to use `source=$0`, `destination=$1`  etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help I just have some minor doubts. I replaced the source and destination folder and it is giving me an error at last line that file does not exist and if I remove file name it shows error unexpected end of the file. Just de be clear I have to run it like a .sh file right. Again thanks for the help. PS: source="home/rushi/Folder1"
destination="home/rushi/Folder2"

Comment: Hi. Have you given the absolute path? eg: source="/home/rushi/Folder1" like that? Yes, you can run it as bash filename.sh or ./filename.sh

Comment: Yes I have given the absolute path.

Comment: Do you have file.txt in the location of the script? Because the above script only copies the files listed in the file.txt file. I understood from your question that you need to copy only some files from a directory to another. So i take the list of files to copy from a file.txt. So provide the correct path to the file in the last line. I think, it should fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply you are very helpful  I made following changes to code and this error occurred:                                                                      `source="home/rushi/Folder1"
destination="home/rushi/Folder2"
done < /home/rushi/Folder2`                                                                    ./COPY.sh: line 6: read: read error: 0: Is a directory I am so sorry I am way to bad with this formating system.